# “that” for emphasis

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

In English, the word *that* can be used as emphasis for adjectives (with some prior context). For example:

> I’m not **that** rich. 
>   She’s not **that** dumb. 
>   Is he **that** mad?

How can we use the same kind of emphasis in German?

Edit:

I know *that* can be translated as *das, dass and diese.* However, those aren’t what I’m looking for. Also, the *that* here refers to some level of the adjective that’s previously stated. It can be used without *not* too, and I’m not sure about *so* (German) since it doesn’t feel like what I’m looking for exactly.

Another example:

> Is he so smart that he got a Nobel Prize?
>   Yes, he’s **that** smart.

Comment: This is also listed here: [dict.cc not that](https://www.dict.cc/?s=not+that)

Comment: Yeah, why not simply look in a dictionary?

Comment: I know "that" can be translated as das, dass and diese. However, those aren't what I'm looking for. Also, the "that" here refers to some level of the adjective that's previously stated. It can be used without "not" too, and I'm not sure about "so" (deutsch) since it doesn't feel like what I'm looking for exactly.

Answer (score 16):

All your examples are about an amount of being rich/dumb/mad. There is the german word

> dermaßen

to express that. In every day conversation one would rather use *so* instead.

> Ich bin nicht **so** reich.
>
> Sie ist nicht **so** dumm.
>
> Ist er **so** böse/wütend/...?

Comment: Although here I would like to add that maost of the time in those case "so" is pronounced as if it had serveral o's (more like "sooo")

Comment: I think "So reich bin nicht nicht." would fit the sentiment better.

Comment: The phrasing implies pointing at somebody else for comparison, and "so" is exactly what you'd use in German; however I'd add that colloquially one would probably use "So(oo) reich bin ich auch wieder nicht", "So dumm ist sie auch wieder nicht."

Answer (score 8):

Well, normally we use "so".

> Ich bin nicht **so** reich
>
> Sie ist nicht **so** dumm
>
> Ist er **so** bescheuert?

Comment: Although here I would like to add that maost of the time in those case "so" is pronounced as if it had serveral o's (more like "sooo")

Answer (score 3):

The general way to express this emphasis is indeed using the word *so.*

> Ist er so bescheuert?

However, thanks to the freedom of German word order, you would likely rearrange to give the emphasised part even more emphasis:

> So reich bin ich nicht.
> So dumm ist sie nicht.
>
> Ist er so schlau, dass er einen Nobelpreis bekommen wird?
> Ja, so schlau ist er.

While this can be done with the question too, I would argue that it is somewhat less common in that case. Meaning that the following sentence is possible, but less likely:

> So bescheuert ist er?

Often, for added emphasis, the *o* of *so* is lengthened and thus sometimes (in chat or text messages) written *sooooo*.

Answer (score -5):

You could say:

> Ich bin nicht **so viel** reich. 
>   Sie ist nicht **so viel** dumm. 
>   Ist er **so viel** bescheuert?

Comment: I am sorry, but no you couldn't. At least not without being seen as a bit strange, at best.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist so viel falsch …

Comment: _Maybe_ "sehr" instead. But even then it would sound weird. "Ich bin nicht **sehr** reich" would be acceptable. Simply "sie ist nicht **so** dumm" would work. "Ist er **so sehr** bescheuert?" probably won't raise an eyebrow.